# RecurrenceTable with defined functions

Tags: difference-equations

I am trying to solve a difference equation using RecurrenceTable as follows.

```
xhat0 = {0.00000001, 256};
boxedx[x_] := Piecewise[{{-2, x < -2}, {2, 2 < x}}, x]
SetAttributes[boxedx, Listable];
test = RecurrenceTable[{xhat[n] == boxedx[xhat[n - 1]],xhat[0] == xhat0}, {xhat}, {n, 1, 4}]
```

If I remove the boxedx function acting on the right hand side, or replace it by a built-in function such as Sqrt, the code works. I tried the definition

```
boxedx[x_List] := Map[Piecewise[{{-2, # < -2}, {2, 2 < #}}, #] &, x]
```

which also resulted in a numerical exception. And if I write the equality as

```
xhat[n] == xhat[n - 1] + {1, 1}
```

a numerical exception happens again. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Does it work if you use Clip[x, {-2, 2}] instead of boxedx?

Comment: It does, I hadn't thought of it! 

I still don't understand why - and Attributes of Clip don't include listable - but  your suggestions solves my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Clip -- it acts on the elements of a list

```
Clip[Range[-5, 5], {-2, 2}]
{-2, -2, -2, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! 

Do you have any idea of why defining a function doesn't work? I'm pretty sure I'll need something more complex sooner or later, so any pointer would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry -- I'm not sure why -- I didn't really understand what you are trying to do in the RecurrenceTable.

Comment: It was a simplified version of my problem, I removed complications in the RecurrenceTable to identify the source of the error messages. Your suggestion of using Clip solved my problem, though I still don't understand what was causing the errors. Thanks!